# Syntax error. Cannot close the echo statement

Tags: php, echo

I have a problem with echo statements. the end result is that it echo everything after the first statement, including all the codes.I know my problem is probably on my first echo statement. And its said to be syntax error but I don' seem to be able to find the problem. So I hope someone can spot my problem.
This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration Result</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['userid'])){
 $userid=$_POST['userid'];
}
else{
 $userid=null;
 echo'<p><font color="red">Please enter your userid!</font></p>';
}
if (!empty($_POST['sex'])){
$sex=$_POST['sex'];
}
else{
$sex=null;
echo '<p><font color="red">Please choose your gender!</font></p>';
}
if(!empty($_POST['pwd'])){
$pwd=$_POST['pwd'];
}
else{
$pwd=null;
echo'<p><font color="red">Please enter your password!</font></p>';
}
if(!empty($_POST['name'])){
$name=$_POST['name'];
}
else{
$name=null;
echo '<p><font color="red">Please enter you name!</font></p>';
}
if(!isset($_POST['day'])){
$day=$_POST['day'];
}
else{
$day=null;
echo '<p><font color="red">Please enter you day of birth!</font></p>'
}
if(!isset($_POST['month'])){
$month=$_POST['month'];
}
else{
$month=null;
echo '<p><font color="red">Please enter you month of birth!</font></p>'
}
if(!empty($_POST['year'])){
$year=$_POST['year'];
}
else{
$year=null;
echo '<p><font color="red">Please enter your year of birth!</font></p>'
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And the result:

```
Please enter your userid!
'; } if (!empty($_POST['sex'])){ $sex=$_POST['sex']; } else{ $sex=null; echo '
Please choose your gender!

'; } if(!empty($_POST['pwd'])){ $pwd=$_POST['pwd'];} else{ $pwd=null; echo'
Please enter your password!

'; } if(!empty($_POST['name'])){ $name=$_POST['name'];} else{ $name=null; echo '
Please enter you name!

'; } if(!isset($_POST['day'])){ $day=$_POST['day'];} else{ $day=null; echo '
Please enter you day of birth!

'} if(!isset($_POST['month'])){ $month=$_POST['month'];} else{ $month=null; echo '
Please enter you month of birth!

'} if(!empty($_POST['year'])){ $year=$_POST['year'];} else{ $year=null; echo '
Please enter your year of birth!

'} ?>
```

Comment: Do a "view source" and you'll probably see the whole code from beginning to end.... looks like your webserver isn't configured to process the PHP file at all

Comment: You missing `;` near line `Please enter you day of birth` same for month & year message.

Comment: There's no space between the first `echo` and the first quote: `echo'`. Add a space and see if that fixes it.

Comment: What's the syntax error you are getting?

Comment: I mean you use notepad for editing, this kind of errors are visible in any IDE..

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a closing semicolon. It will work like this:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['userid'])) {
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
} else {
    $userid = null;
    echo '<p><font color="red">Please enter your userid!</font></p>';
}
if (!empty($_POST['sex'])) {
    $sex = $_POST['sex'];
} else {
    $sex = null;
    echo '<p><font color="red">Please choose your gender!</font></p>';
}
if (!empty($_POST['pwd'])) {
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
} else {
    $pwd = null;
    echo '<p><font color="red">Please enter your password!</font></p>';
}
if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
} else {
    $name = null;
    echo '<p><font color="red">Please enter you name!</font></p>';
}
if (!isset($_POST['day'])) {
    $day = $_POST['day'];
} else {
    $day = null;
    echo '<p><font color="red">Please enter you day of birth!</font></p>';
}
if (!isset($_POST['month'])) {
    $month = $_POST['month'];
} else {
    $month = null;
    echo '<p><font color="red">Please enter you month of birth!</font></p>';
}
if (!empty($_POST['year'])) {
    $year = $_POST['year'];
} else {
    $year = null;
    echo '<p><font color="red">Please enter your year of birth!</font></p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo '<p><font color="red">Please enter you day of birth!</font></p>';` //you missed semicolon ";" for 3 echo

Answer (score 0):

Your last three echo statements are missing the closing semi-colons `;`

Answer (score 0):

You missed ; semi colons in these lines of code:

```
else {
            $day = null;
            echo '<p><font color="red">Please enter you day of birth!</font></p>';
        }
        if (!isset($_POST['month'])) {
            $month = $_POST['month'];
        } else {
            $month = null;
            echo '<p><font color="red">Please enter you month of birth!</font></p>';
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['year'])) {
            $year = $_POST['year'];
        } else {
            $year = null;
            echo '<p><font color="red">Please enter your year of birth!</font></p>';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not interpreted - you have to enable PHP in your server or enable it for proper file extension. I hope you're using some server? ;)
Additionally there are some parse errors in this code mentioned already by the others (but that you should see as parse error or blank page if error reporting is turned off).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 3 semicolons. i have fixed it now try.

```
echo '<p><font color="red">Please enter you day of birth!</font></p>';}
if(!isset($_POST['month'])){
$month=$_POST['month'];}
else{
$month=null;
echo '<p><font color="red">Please enter you month of birth!</font></p>';}
if(!empty($_POST['year'])){
$year=$_POST['year'];}
else{
$year=null;
echo '<p><font color="red">Please enter your year of birth!</font></p>';}
```